# C# - Passing different type of objects through the same method

Tags: c#, .net

**Original Question**

So I have this 3 objects...

```
public class obj1
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class obj2
{
  public int AccNum { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class obj3
{
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

... and one method that is supposed to receive one of them, after evaluating the object type the program should decide which function to call.

I've tried with generics but it doesn't work as I expected. So far this is what I've got...

```
    public class NotificationHelper: INotificationHelper
    {

        public bool SendNotification<TNotInfo>(TNotInfo obj) where TNotInfo : class
        {
            if (contract.GetType() == typeof (obj1))
            {
                var sender = new SendSMS();
                return sender.Send(obj);
            }
            if (contract.GetType() == typeof(obj2))
            {
                var sender = new SendPush();
                return sender.Send(obj);
            }
            else
            {
                var sender = new SendEmail();
                return sender.Send(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

but I get the error "Cannot convert from TNotInfo to Models.obj1". Is there any way to overcome this issue? Or I have to change my logic?

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

***Edit**

```
using System;

namespace EmailNotifications
{

    public interface IEmailNotification
    {
        void SendEmailNotification();
    }

    public class EmailNotificationA : IEmailNotification
    {

        public void SendEmailNotification(Contract1 a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending EmailNotificationA ({a})");
        }
    }

    public class EmailNotificationB : IEmailNotification
    {
        public void SendEmailNotification(Contract2 b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending EmailNotificationB ({b})");
        }
    }

    public class EmailNotificationC : IEmailNotification
    {

        public void SendEmailNotification(Contrac3 c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending EmailNotificationC ({c})");
        }
    }

    public class EmailNotificationService
    {
        private readonly IEmailNotification _emailNotification;

        public EmailNotificationService(IEmailNotification emailNotification)
        {
            this._emailNotification = emailNotification;
        }

        public void ServiceHelper()
        {
            _emailNotification.SendEmailNotification();
        }
    }
}
```

Above solution is what I was trying to achieve, applying strategy design pattern. But I couldn't manage to make my interface method receive different objects, this is required because each notification has is own implementation. As visible at the none working example above, I have 3 different implementation of the same method all of them receiving different objects. Any idea of how to make this logic work?

Comment: The reason for the error is that it doesn't know how to convert `obj` into `Models.obj1` since all it knows about obj is that it is a class. So effectively it is of type object. In this case you would need to cast the object to the right type. Also you are not actually using the Generic Type parameter so you would be as well off changing the method signature  to `SendNotifications(object obj)` but of course now you look at that and think there is something wrong because you really shouldn't be just passing in an obj. Can you just overload this method to do what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach will be overload methods.
Because you have different logic based on the given type. And types have nothing in common (interface/abstract class).

```
public class NotificationHelper
{
    public bool SendNotification(obj1 obj)
    {
        var sender = new SendSMS();
        return sender.Send(obj);
    }

    public bool SendNotification(obj2 obj)
    {
        var sender = new SendPush();
        return sender.Send(obj);
    }

    public bool SendNotification(obj3 obj)
    {
        var sender = new SendEmail();
        return sender.Send(obj);
    }
}
```

Then using will be clear enough

```
var someObject = GetObjectFromSomeWhere();
var isSuccessful = SendNotification(someObject);
```

Comment: This approach would violate the open-closed principle. Every new form of object would require a new overloaded method. It would be better to have a touch of redundancy that my answer uses in order to keep all the code concise and self-contained within the relevant classes only.

Answer (score 16):

This is the kind of thing that interfaces were designed to do. First, define a common interface:

```
public interface INotifier
{
    bool Notify();
}
```

Second, implement it in your `objX` classes:

```
public class obj1 : INotifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Notify()
    {
        var sender = new SendSMS();
        return sender.Send(this);
    }
}

public class obj2 : INotifier
{
    public int AccNum { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Notify()
    {
        var sender = new SendPush();
        return sender.Send(this);
    }
}

public class obj3 : INotifier
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public bool Notify()
    {
        var sender = new SendEmail();
        return sender.Send(this);
    }
}
```

And finally, change your notification method to accept the interface type as the parameter:

```
public class NotificationHelper : INotificationHelper
{
    public bool SendNotification(INotifier obj)
    {
        return obj.Notify();
    }
}
```

---

**Edit (2019):**

I'm revisiting this answer as it seems to be getting a fair amount of visibility. OP has probably long since moved on, but for others that may stumble upon this answer, here's another solution.

I still believe that interfaces are the way to go. However, the interface suggested above is extremely generic and ultimately not terribly useful. It also runs into some DRY violations because, as Fabio said in a comment, if two `objX` classes implement notifications in the same way, this approach forces you to duplicate the code between them.

Instead of one global interface, instead have interfaces for each specific notification task, i.e. `ISMSNotification`, `IPushNotification`, `IEmailNotification`. You can then use the mixin pattern to give each interface instance a default implementation of the send method:

```
interface ISmsNotifier
{
  int SmsId { get; }
  string SmsName { get; }
}

static class ISmsNotifierExtensions 
{
  public static bool NotifySms(this ISmsNotifier obj) 
  {
    var sender = new SendSMS();
    return sender.Send(obj);
  }
}

// ---------------------------------------------

interface IPushNotifier 
{
  int PushAccNum { get; }
  string PushName { get; }
}

static class IPushNotifierExtensions 
{
  public static bool NotifyPush(this IPushNotifier obj) 
  {
    var sender = new SendEmail();
    return sender.Send(obj);
  }
}

// ---------------------------------------------

interface IEmailNotifier 
{
  string EmailAddress { get; }
  string EmailPhone { get; }
}

static class IEmailNotifierExtensions 
{
  public static bool NotifyEmail(this IEmailNotifier obj) 
  {
    var sender = new SendEmail();
    return sender.Send(obj);
  }
}
```

You can then implement it in the `objX` classes like so:

```
public class obj1 : INotifier, ISmsNotifier 
{
  public int SmsId { get; set; }
  public string SmsName { get; set; }

  public bool Notify() => this.NotifySms();
}

public class obj2 : INotifier, IPushNotifier
{
    public int PushAccNum { get; set; }
    public string PushName { get; set; }

    public bool Notify() => this.NotifyPush();
} 

public class obj3 : INotifier, IEmailNotifier
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmailPhone { get; set; }

    public bool Notify() => this.NotifyEmail();
}
```

Notice that using this approach it's easy to not only support objects which use identical notification systems, you can also support objects with *multiple* notification systems:

```
public class obj4 : INotifier, IEmailNotifier, IPushNotifier
{
    public int PushAccNum { get; set; }
    public string PushName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmailPhone { get; set; }

    public bool Notify() => this.NotifyEmail() && this.NotifyPush();
}
```

You might notice that this approach makes `NotificationHelper` obsolete since it's no longer necessary to pass the objects through a processing step to determine which notification system to process the object through. That is true, and maybe rightfully so, since the objects should be fully capable of deciding that for themselves (depending on your mentality approaching this problem). However, `NotificationHelper` may still have its uses, such as if you wanted to preprocess the information that's getting sent to the notification services, or if you wanted a common point of entry to help with mocking and testing.

**C# 8 Note:**

A proposed feature of C# 8 is the ability to give interfaces a default implementation of methods within the interface definition itself. When (if) that happens, you don't need to use the mixin pattern anymore and can directly define the default method implementations in the interfaces. The feature hasn't yet been finalized, but it might look something like this:

```
interface ISmsNotifier 
{
  int SmsId { get; }
  string SmsName { get; }

  public bool NotifySms() 
  {
    var sender = new SendSMS();
    return sender.Send(this);
  }
}

// ---------------------------------------------

interface IPushNotifier 
{
  int PushAccNum { get; }
  string PushName { get; }

  public bool NotifyPush() 
  {
    var sender = new SendEmail();
    return sender.Send(this);
  }
}

// ---------------------------------------------

interface IEmailNotifier 
{
  string EmailAddress { get; }
  string EmailPhone { get; }

  public bool NotifyEmail() 
  {
    var sender = new SendEmail();
    return sender.Send(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Liskov Substitution, "L" character in S.O.L.I.D Principles describes this situation. Perfectly explained!

Comment: This will move responsibility of sending object to object itself.

Comment: @ArkadiuszRaszeja, this is not `Liskov Substitution` - this approach even violate somehow "Single responsibility principle" ( "S" character in S.O.L.I.D), because now `obj1` is responsible for carrying data and for sending himself somewhere

Comment: @Fabio This is an explanation of how to cleanly do generally what OP is trying to do without explicit casting, overloading, or coupling. Judging from what code he has shown, there are likely design problems in the `SendX` classes as well that, were they corrected, would make this approach even more concise.

Comment: @Abion47, why overloading is bad things? Your approach is correct and purely object-oriented(related data and behaviour are in same object). As I seen, OP want to have sending method outside of those classes.

Comment: With your approach class `NotificationHelper` become useless. Because if I have `obj1` - I can always call `((INotifier)obj1).Send();`

Comment: @Fabio I didn't say it was bad, but in this instance, an interface is better design. Each of the objects performs a similar function, but the relevant function needs to be performed depending on the specific type of object passed. That is a _textook_ use case for interfaces.

Comment: @Fabio And like I already said, his code has telltale signs of other design flaws that, were they corrected, would render all of this moot. As it stands, both of our solutions are valid solutions but because of the way the code is structured, they both inevitably offend a major design principle. Without being able to critique OP's entire project, however, I stand by my saying that interfaces are the more preferred method as the resulting design problem is less severe.

Comment: @Fabio Yes, you _could_ just use `_obj1.Send` in this case, and in fact, I would say that you _should_. The whole point of the Liskov Substitution principle is to do away with pointless helper methods like this.

Comment: Guys, in first place thanks for the help. I might had mislead you by trying to reduce the amount of code on my post, because the real deal in here is I'm trying to apply strategy design pattern where I have 3 different implementations in one method. I will update my question with the actual architecture showing the SDP, Hopefully it helps the discussion.

Comment: @iniestar If it can be applied to either an interface design or method overloading, then do it. If not, then you probably should figure out a way to do it anyway, since one method fulfilling three different roles just reeks of code smell.

Comment: @Abion47, I am very sorry but `Liskov Substitution` have nothing to do with OP question and your solution. Liskov Substitution principles stays that instance of derived class can be replaced with parent class without breaking expected flow(return value, exceptions etc.)

Comment: @Fabio That... is true. I've had a check again, and it seems I got thrown off by a specific example one site's explanation of it was giving. Well regardless, while I was wrong about the application of that principle, the rest of my points still stand.

Comment: Convincing you wasn't my intention :). It was useful and interesting to check own thought against others. Keeping "sending" logic outside of objects itself will give you possibility "freely" refactoring/changing this logic without touching all objects. What if you have another object `obj7` which have different structure but need to use `SendEmail` sender as `obj1` - you end up with duplication or will try to build some workaround with inheritance. So responsibility of sending should be in separated class and it is ok to change it if "sending" logic changes.

Comment: @Fabio That is true, but like I said, that is a side effect of the design surrounding the `obj1/SendSMS` etc. class pair system that OP has going on. It seems like instead of having a sender system that he passes data to, it's like he is taking data and building a system around it. That kind of structure would incorporate design principle violations no matter what you tried to build around it, your method overloading approach included.

Comment: @Fabio and Abion47... I'm reading your back and fourth and it made me understand that my design it's the cause of the problem. Thanks guys, as a newbie on back-end development I am not aware of this concepts but I'm trying to learn them. Now what would be your suggestion to correctly solve the problem instead keeping the bad design?

Comment: @iniestar, information you provided in the question not enough for suggesting. As Abion47 noticed: _It seems like instead of having a sender system that he passes data to, it's like he is taking data and building a system around it_. Usually this kind of question(about design) is off topic here, because of different points of view where answers are very close to be opinion based. You can try to ask design question on [http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Fabio I edited the question, can you have a look at it and see if its more clear now? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a parent class from which these 3 inherit

```
public class ParentType { }
public class Obj1 : ParentType { ... }
```

The method would then just request the parent type, such as:

```
public bool SendNotification(ParentType obj) { ... }
```

Comment: This wouldn't really help. `sender.Send` has multiple overloads and they would each accept one of the specific types. Thus without changing the code in `SendNotification` you'd get much the same error.

Comment: For my own learning, would you mind clarifying? My understanding was that the error was thrown because an instance of Obj1 does not match TNotInfo in the method declaration. I would have thought that having a parent class would address that issue. Also, I believe the `sender.send()` is not overloaded, but instead the `sender` variable is instantiated with different classes of Sender from what I can see.

Comment: So I assume that sender.Send has signatures like `sender.Send(ChildType1 obj)` and `sender.Send(ChildType2 obj)` from the fact that the question says "after evaluating the object type the program should decide which function to cal". So you will have the problem that there is no method that will accept an obj and no implicit conversions can be made that will work. Therefore you will still get an error saying words to the effect of "the best overloaded method has invalid arguments, couldn't convert obj to ChildType1".

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for responding. I think I was a little lazy with writing my answer. I was suggesting that the code internal to `SendNotification()` (which determines how `sender` is instantiated stay roughly the same as provided in the original question. The method accepts the Child object, determines its type, instantiates sender and calls `sender.send()` accordingly, as it does in the original sample in the question. Would that not work? Just to add, I know this isn't the best solution, but I'd like to be sure as to whether it would lead to a working solution.

Comment: The reason why the original code doesn't work is because when `sender.send()` is being called it doesn't know which overload to use. The OP got "Cannot convert from TNotInfo to Models.obj1" whereas you would get "Cannot convert from ParentType to Models.obj1". Essentially your solution doesn't address the issue that you need to cast the object before calling the overloaded method.