# C# map a list of abstract class objects to derived class for method overloading

Tags: c#, methods, overloading, abstract, derived

I am in a situation where I am iterating a `List<Animal>` and want a `Handler` class to handle each element according to its derived type. The way I'm doing it is weird and hard to follow. Is there a better way?

The purpose of the Handler class is to encapsulate the code for talking to the database, I don't want the animals to have any reference to it. I just want to point a hose of animals at the database and have square pegs go in square holes, and round pegs in round holes.

Thanks in advance.

```
abstract class Animal
{
  public void update() { }
  public virtual void Handle(Handler handler) { }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
  public override void Handle(Handler handler) => handler.Handle(this); 
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
  public override void Handle(Handler handler) => handler.Handle(this); 
}

public class Handler
{
  private Clinic clinic; //only the handler talks to the database
  public void Handle(Animal animal) => animal.Handle(this); 
  public void Handle(Dog dog) { /* write dog fields to database */ }
  public void Handle(Cat cat) { /* write cat fields to database */ } 
}

public void main()
{
  List<Animal> animals = getAnimals(); 
  Handler handler = new Handler(); 
  foreach(var animal in animals)
  {
    handler.handle(animal); 
  }
}
```

Edit:
I think my question is essentially answered here: [Passing different type of objects through the same method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183133/c-sharp-passing-different-type-of-objects-through-the-same-method).

> It seems like instead of having a sender system that he passes data to, it's like he is taking data and building a system around it. That kind of structure would incorporate design principle violations no matter what you tried to build around it.

I think the answer is to move the database write into the factory that generates the animals. This means I can't prevalidate the entire set of animals before writing, but it cleans out all the indirection and potentially removes the animal and handler classes entirely.

Comment: You could take a look at the `Visitor pattern`. This pattern addresses your problem. There a serveral descriptions as well as examples for this.

Comment: Add more details as to what you actually do with your animals and your DB. It's hard to suggest based on a do-nothing contrivance

Comment: I have an interface that lets me set values on named fields. I have a set of data classes containing different fields. I want to iterate over a list of objects and call interface.setvalue(obj.fieldname, obj.fieldvalue). I'd prefer all calls to setvalue to be in one place, for readability and transparency. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, starting from version 7.0, you can make use of pattern matching to handle each concrete instance separately.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public abstract class Animal
    {
      public void update() { }
      public virtual void Handle(Handler handler) { }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal {}

    public class Cat : Animal {}
    
    public class Handler
    {
      public void Handle(List<Animal> animals)
      {
        foreach (var animal in animals)
        {
            switch (animal)
            {
                case Cat cat:
                    Handle(cat);
                    break;
                case Dog dog:
                    Handle(dog);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
      }

      public void Handle(Dog dog) { Console.WriteLine("Wrote a dog field"); }
      public void Handle(Cat cat) { Console.WriteLine("Wrote a cat field"); } 
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>(){
            new Dog(),
            new Cat(),
            new Dog(),
        };
        
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.Handle(animals);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use LINQ's `OfType<T>` method to filter out instances of each concrete class and handle them that way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those extra Handle Methods,

```
abstract class Animal
{
  public void update() { }
  public virtual void Handle(Handler handler)=> handler.Handle(this);
}

class Dog
{
  public override void Handle(Handler handler)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Dog handler");
     base.Handle(this); 
  }
}

public class Handler
{
  private Clinic clinic; //only the handler talks to the database
  public void Handle(Animal animal) => animal.Handle(this); 
}
```

Now when you call `Handler.Handle(new Dog())`, the call will be dispatched to dog.Handle. That's how `Polymorphism` works.

However, I believe the relationship should not be two ways until absolutely needed. You should know which one among them has the actual business logic.

Like does the Animal really needs to have an instance of handler? Or you can manage with just the Id instead of actual reference.

Comment: "_You don't need those extra Handle Methods_" Then how would you access derived members?

Comment: Added more details to explain the working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dynamic` to solve this, but be warned: `dynamic` can introduce a lot of overhead.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animals = new List<Animal>()
        {
            new Dog(),
            new Cat(),
            new Rabbit()
        };

        var handler = new Handler();

        foreach (var animal in animals)
        {
            handler.Handle(animal);
        }
    }

    public sealed class Handler
    {
        public void Handle(Animal animal)
        {
            handleImp((dynamic)animal);
        }

        void handleImp(Cat cat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling cat");
        }

        void handleImp(Dog dog)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling dog");
        }

        void handleImp(Animal animal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling unrecognised animal");
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    public void Update() { }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}

public class Rabbit: Animal
{
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Handling dog
Handling cat
Handling unrecognised animal
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Um6q38)